# Default template for Joomla

Tags: joomla

I made a wrong choice in the configuration of Joomla.

I wanted to have Default English (GB) Sample Data but I gave the first choice.

[image]

I need the protostar template as it is in “Default English (GB) Sample Data” version and not as the default. I have to work with the project I created and I can’t create a new one in order to set the right choice.
What I tried is to take the version of protostar template from the version of “Default English (GB) Sample Data” an make it a zip and upload it as a new extension-template.

But it gives me the message

```
   Warning
   Template Install: There is already a Template using the named directory: Install. Are you trying to install the same template again?
```

What can I do in order to upload the version I want?

Comment: [Joomla.StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I put it http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/default-template-for-joomla

Comment: Good job. It's not as active there as over here but you should get your answer before too long.

Comment: I don't have the latest Joomla installed anywhere. I used to play with it a few years back but anything I'd suggest from memory would likely be wildly out of date now. I know Joomla v2 and from what I hear Joomla 3 was a huge rewrite/reworking of how things are done.

Answer (score 3):

The sample data is part of the main Joomla install and nothing to do with the template.

You can find the sql in the Joomla package under installation/sql/postgresql

There is a good chance that executing this SQL would add the data for you (make a backup first if you do that).

As there isn't actually much sample data included with that option (in Joomla 3, anyway), you may just be better installing a new version of Joomla somewhere and using that to study how it works, copying anything you need onto your main site.

Answer (score 2):

Protostar is exactly the same in all of the sample data; what could possibly differ is some of the style settings ... but more important is probably that you are seeing some different modules, The default sample data has a few modules enabled including one displaying an image (with the blue flowers).  Is that possibly what you are missing?

`(7, 'protostar', 0, '1', 'protostar - Default', '{"templateColor":"","logoFile":"","googleFont":"1","googleFontName":"Open+Sans","fluidContainer":"0"}'),`

Is exactly what is there in the template styles, as you can see except for selecting a Google Font there is not much going on.